# Reconciling: A mixed model with random effect shows significant differences in fixed effects but has overlapping CI?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, lme4-nlme, bootstrap

I'm trying to reconcile with a mixed model with random effect shows significant differences in fixed effects but has overlapping confidence intervals.

Here is data computing temperature of litterfall across three foresttypes `A`, `B`, `C` with time as a random factor. I computed it in two ways: a classic `lmer` and using bootstrapped method. Both gave me similar estimates and CI. Particularly, `A` (Intercept) was "significantly" different from `C`.

```
model: lmer(literfall.temperature ~ Forest + (1 | time))

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       14.77000    2.12477 11.01406   6.951  2.4e-05 ***
B                 0.34750     0.09304 58.00000   3.735   0.00043 ***
C                 -0.27833    0.09304 58.00000  -2.992  0.00407 *
```

Confidence Intervals

```
                       2.5 %      97.5 %
.sig01             4.9471113 11.17356508
.sigma             0.2676353  0.38326916
(Intercept)       10.4417210 19.09827884
B                  0.1653110  0.52968898
C                 -0.4605223 -0.09614435
```

The Q-Q plots

[image]

The Q-Q plots weren't the greatest. So I used a bootstrap function (n = 999) to estimate mean and CI (`boot_summary` from `boot.pval` package in R)

```
                    Estimate    lower.CI    Upper.CI    p-val
(Intercept)         14.7700000  10.7808981  18.92891294 0.000
        B           0.3475000   0.1710896   0.51902761  0.000
        C           -0.2783333  -0.4546589  -0.09934883 0.004
```

I get similar results. These don't look significantly different to me as indicated by the p-val as they have overlapping CIs. I'm trying to reconcile why. Any suggestions? I have used other families as well but with no luck.

[image]

Comment: Where are the "overlapping CIs"?  None of your CIs include 0, which is consistent with the fact that all of your p values are below 0.05. So ... what's the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: How did you draw the last figure? I'm guessing that it is a plot of the *marginal* distributions, i.e. it doesn't account for the among-time variation (which *is* accounted for in your model)